# jQuery Ajax request not reaching PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to create a mail form which has javascript validation. The form values should be send with ajax to a php script which emails the data to an emailadress.

However, Neither the php code, succes or the error jquery callbacks gets called, nor are there any logs in the javascript console in chrome.

this is my simplified html page:

```
<form id="mail-form">
    <div class="input-row">
    <div class="label"><label for="name">Your name: *</label></div>
    <div class="input"><input type="text" name="name" id="name" maxlength="50"/></div>
        <input id="submit-button" type="submit" value="send"/>
</form>
```

my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var form = $("#mail-form");

    form.submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        send(form);
    }
});

function send(form) {

    var formData = { name: $("#name").val(),
        email: $("#email").val(),
        phone: $("#phone").val(),
        message: $("#message").val(),
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/scripts/mailer.php",
        datatype: "text",
        data: formData,
        succes: function (data) {
            onSucces();
        },
        error: function () {
            onError();
        }
    });
}
```

and my simplified php file:

```
$myemail = "someone@something.com";
$subject = "test";

$message = $_POST["message"];

mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

echo "ok";
```

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong? I also tried easy get methods, but they won't reach the server either.

Comment: I don't know if this is lost in translation from an IDE to stack but `success` is spelled like that and `$.ajax` expects it to be as so.

Comment: There appears to be an extra bracket in your submit call via jQuery

Comment: The way to track down things like this (bad syntax) is using your browser's Javascript debugger - Chrome has a particularly good one.  You'll see as soon as the page loads that your JS is invalid, which can really speed up debugging.

Comment: I checked the console while I was busy, but it was completely empty.  There was no syntax error shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try it like this:

change:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var form = $("#mail-form");

    form.submit(function () {
        e.preventDefault();
        send(form);
        }
    });
});
```

to:

```
$("#mail-form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        send(form);
});
```

so it looks like this:

```
$("#mail-form").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        send(form);
});

function send(form) {

    var formData = { name: $("#name").val(),
        email: $("#email").val(),
        phone: $("#phone").val(),
        message: $("#message").val(),
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/scripts/mailer.php",
        datatype: "text",
        data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            onSucces();
        },
        error: function () {
            onError();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I did wrong, mistyping success.. I feel kinda stupid right now. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this for your JavaScript; `success` was wrong and you had a pointless bracket in your `submit()` call:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var form = $("#mail-form");
    form.submit(function (e) {
        send(form);
        e.preventDefault();
        return(false);
    });
});
function send(form) {
    var formData = {
        name: $("#name").val(),
        email: $("#email").val(),
        phone: $("#phone").val(),
        message: $("#message").val(),
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/scripts/mailer.php",
        datatype: "text",
        data: formData,
        success: function(data){
            onSucces();
        },
        error: function(){
            onError();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You were right! mistyped success.... also the useless bracket was caused with copy pasting ;). i had a check there if the form is valid, then it should call the send function. the bracket's from the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

You should never ever rely on data verification at client side.

To your question, use alert to confirm that neither success or error callback functions are being executed. You can also remove the dataType to see if that makes any difference.

You can also do this

```
var formData = form.serialize();
```

instead of this

```
var formData = { name: $("#name").val(),
    email: $("#email").val(),
    phone: $("#phone").val(),
    message: $("#message").val(),
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'm going to add serverside validation as well.